# Android, org.json.jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject

Tags: java, android

I am trying to exchange data with my web server. The code I am having trouble with is:

```
public void getOnlineData(View view) {
        try {
            // http://androidarabia.net/quran4android/phpserver/connecttoserver.php
            int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 10000;
            // Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - start");
            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
                    TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            //
            HttpParams p = new BasicHttpParams();
            // p.setParameter("name", pvo.getName());
            p.setParameter("user", "1");

            // Instantiate an HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String url = "http://twenty5eight.co.uk/portal/" + 
                         "json/json.php";
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Instantiate a GET HTTP method
            try {
                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - start");
                //
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                        2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "1"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                        responseHandler);
                // Parse
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("posts");
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = 
                       new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String s = e.getString("post");
                    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(s);

                    map.put("id", jObject.getString("id"));
                    map.put("name", jObject.getString("name"));
                    map.put("birthyear", jObject.getString("birthyear"));

                    mylist.add(map);
                }
                Toast.makeText(this, responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - end");

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }       
    }
```

Edit: No errors are coming up on the log. The error handler in place is saying "Request failed: org.json.JSONException:Value  of type org.json.jsonArray cannot be converted to jsonobject".

Comment: please put the logcat

Comment: post the string you are try to convert in JSONObject

Comment: Also check if you are running network related operation on the main ui thread.

Comment: You need to provide some indication of the error, a stack trace at least.  Also, remember that most people answer questions at SO for fun in their leisure time, so please refrain from saying how much of a hurry you are in.

Comment: I never said I was in a hurry, merely stating that SO members would be able to help me quicker than it me trying to figure it out due to my lack of android knowledge.

Comment: still to understand what's happening you should post the String you are trying to convert. Propably the string represents an JSONArray instead of a JSONObject

Comment: of course no error shows in the log, since you toast it and then discard it ... don't toast exceptions. it's ugly and useless. e.printstacktrace, then come back with the actual log of the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your url, the data is a JSON array. You are trying to create a JSONObject from the String of a JSONArray. It cannot work this way. Create a JSONArray instead.

Also, still from your url, there is no key 'posts' anywhere in your json.

Comment: you have 99% of it already. Assuming you understood how to try to create a JSONObject from the request result, you should be able to figure how to create a JSONArray instead.

Comment: Thanks njzk2 for pointing me in the right direction, have it working now. :)